# Custom product type don't allow update in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a custom product type but when updating a previously created product, it is not updated. For example: if the product I want to update is a simple type, when I change it to my custom product type and save, it is still maintained as a simple type instead of my custom product type.

You can see a gif of the problem here: https://media.giphy.com/media/5z83HMwdPy5twyUOGT/giphy.gif

Currently I have version 3.4.5 of Woocommerce and version 5.0-alpha-43406 of WordPress.

Next I leave the code used to generate the type of personalized product:

**WC_Product_canopytour.php**

```
class WC_Product_CanopyTour extends WC_Product {
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        $this->product_type = 'canopytour';
        $this->virtual = 'yes';
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }

    public function get_type() {
        return 'canopytour';
    }
}
```

**class-woocommerce-custom-product.php**

```
    public function register_canopytour_product_type() {
        include_once(plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'woocommerce/WC_Product_canopytour.php');
    }

    public function add_canopytour_product( $types ) {
        $types[ 'canopytour' ] = __( 'Canopy Tour', $this->wcb );
        return $types;
    }

    public function get_tour_product_class($classname, $product_type) {
        if ( $product_type === "canopytour" ) {
            $classname = 'WC_Product_CanopyTour';
        }
        return $classname;
    }

    public function wcb_admin_footer() {
        if ( 'product' != get_post_type() ) :
            return;
        endif;

        ?><script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
                jQuery( '.options_group.pricing' ).addClass( 'show_if_canopytour show_if_variable_canopytour show_if_simple show_if_external' ).show();
                jQuery( 'li.general_options.general_tab' ).addClass( 'show_if_canopytour show_if_variable_canopytour show_if_simple show_if_external' ).show();
            });
        </script><?php
    }

    public function add_canopytour_tab($tabs) {
        $tabs['canopytour'] = array(
            'label'     => __( 'Canopy Tour', 'woocommerce' ),
            'target'    => 'canopytour_options',
            'class'     => array( 'show_if_canopytour', 'show_if_variable_canopytour'  ),
        );
        return $tabs;
    }

    public function canopytour_options_product_tab_content() {
        global $post; ?>
        <div id='canopytour_options' class='panel woocommerce_options_panel'>
            <div class='options_group'>
            </div>
        </div><?php
    }

    function hide_wcb_data_panel( $tabs) {
        // Other default values for 'attribute' are; general, inventory, shipping, linked_product, variations, advanced
        $tabs['shipping']['class'][] = 'hide_if_canopytour hide_if_variable_canopytour';
        return $tabs;
    }
```

**class-wcb.php**

```
require_once plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'includes/woocommerce/class-woocommerce-custom-product.php';

private function define_admin_hooks() {

        $plugin_admin = new WCB_Admin( $this->get_wcb(), $this->get_version() );

        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_styles' );
        $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_scripts' );

        if ($this->is_woocommerce_active()) {
            $woo_ct = new WCB_Woocommerce_CanopyTour_Product_Type( $this->get_wcb(), $this->get_version() );
            $this->loader->add_action( 'init', $woo_ct, 'register_canopytour_product_type' );
            $this->loader->add_filter( 'product_type_selector', $woo_ct, 'add_canopytour_product' );
            $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', $woo_ct, 'get_tour_product_class', 10, 2 ); 
            $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_head', $woo_ct, 'wcb_admin_head' );
            $this->loader->add_action( 'admin_footer', $woo_ct, 'wcb_admin_footer' );
            $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', $woo_ct, 'add_canopytour_tab' );
            $this->loader->add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', $woo_ct, 'canopytour_options_product_tab_content' );
            $this->loader->add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple_rental', $woo_ct, 'save_canopytour_option_field'  );
            $this->loader->add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable_rental', $woo_ct, 'save_canopytour_option_field'  );
            $this->loader->add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', $woo_ct, 'hide_wcb_data_panel' );

            $this->loader->add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', $woo_ct, 'wcb_children_product_field' );
            $this->loader->add_action( 'save_post', $woo_ct, 'wcb_children_price_save_product' );
        }
    }
```

With this code, the type of customized product is added to the product information selection. I can also see the custom tab when I select the type of product created. But when saving the select type of product is not saved, it returns to the initial value.

> I have the source code of my plugin in github, if you could give it a
>   view, maybe something is wrong in my code:
>   https://github.com/jesus997/Woocommerce-Canopy-Booking
>
> Steps to start the project:
>
> - Clone the repository
> - Inside the plugin folder run `npm install`
> - Run yarn build or yarn dev to compile the assets

Comment: Hello and Welcome on Stackoverflow. Don't expect people to dig into a full git repository they don't know about to help you to fix a bug (with a so poor description of the issue), This is not how things work. Please read how to [ask] question and how to create [mcve] and then edit your question to include for instance the relevant part of the code that don't work.

Comment: @baptistemm Okay, I feel this. Now edit the question by adding the code I have to add the custom product type :)

Comment: You should provide a a zipped precompiled plugin link (ready to use) instead of something that need to be downloaded localy, compiled and uploaded in a test web site. Your actual question code is not testable, so not complete and not verifiable. Remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"***.

Answer (score 1):

I found why it does not work for me. I added the following code to make an ACF be within the Product Data metabox:

```
$("#canopytour_options .options_group").append($("#acf-group_5b8804f5a1b49"));
```

Apparently this does not work properly since it does not save the type of product chosen, always keep `simple'.

Thanks for your time.